# Filter an array of objects to render items according to checkboxes selected in React using hooks

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, filter, react-hooks

What am I missing here?? I'm stuck trying to filter an array of objects conditionally in React. I have everything set up and working as I believe it should, but I think I'm just mixing a few things up in my inexperience.

Ultimately I want to have all my objects rendered at start, but then filter according to checkboxes selected. For some reason the conditional statement for what to render is not working at all, and while I'm able to get my checkboxes state stored and changed with each click, I am not able to get it to filter.

Here is my code for the component(StoneDisplay.js) This renders the list of checkboxes for filtering the list of stones to display, as well as the container that displays the list of stones. It contains instances of State for my checkboxes, along with the conditional rendering code for which stones to display. To state the obvious, without the conditional code, all items render fine.

```
import React, { /* useEffect, */ useState } from 'react'
import StoneFilter from '../StoneFilter/StoneFilter'
import Stone from '../Stone/Stone'

import './StoneDisplay.css'

const StoneDisplay = ({ stones }) => {
  const [checkedType, setCheckedType] = useState({})
  const [checkedColor, setCheckedColor] = useState({})
  //const [stonesToShow, setStonesToShow] = useState(stones)   // for useEffect
    console.log('stones in StoneDisplay: ', stones)
    //console.log('stonesToShow in Display: ', stonesToShow)  // for useEffect
    console.log('checkedType in StoneDisplay: ', checkedType)
    console.log('checkedColor in StoneDisplay: ', checkedColor)
  
  ///// This is code I am trying to filter stones conditionally without instance of state. /////

  const stonesToShow = (checkedType === {} && checkedColor === {}) // (checkedType.length === 0 && checkedColor.length === 0) tried this too, but had difficulty with length and current setup..
  ? stones 
  : stones.filter(item => item.type === checkedType && item.color === checkedColor) // need to figure what is wrond with this filter

  //stones.filter((item) => true) // Use this filter to 'override' filter to show rendering functions work.

  console.log('checkedType.length: ', checkedType.length) // attempt to try and use .length for initial statement for conditional
  console.log('checkedColor.length: ', checkedColor.length)// i.e. (checkedType.length === 0 && checkedColor.length === 0) ? ..

  ///// This code I'm trying to filter stones using state/useEffect that has been recommended. /////

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setStonesToShow(currentStones => {
  //     console.log('currentStones in useEffect: ', currentStones)

  //     return currentStones.filter((item) => true); // Use this filter to 'override' filter to show rendering functions work.
      
  //     //return currentStones.filter(item => item.type === checkedType && item.color === checkedColor) // Need to fix this
  //   })
  // }, [checkedType, checkedColor])
  
  return (
    <section className="stone">
      <StoneFilter
        checkedType={checkedType}
        setCheckedType={setCheckedType}
        checkedColor={checkedColor}
        setCheckedColor={setCheckedColor}
      />
      <div className="stone__carousel">
        {stonesToShow.map((stone) =>
          <Stone
          key={stone.id}
          stone={stone}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default StoneDisplay
```

Here is the component containing my checkboxes. I keep coming back here as I believe my problems could be from how I'm handling/saving the state. I am unable to determine how/why though..

```
import React from 'react'
import StoneFilterListItem from '../StoneFilterListItem/StoneFilterListItem'
import checkboxesType from './checkboxesType'
import checkboxesColor from './checkboxesColor'

import './StoneFilter.css'

const StoneFilter = ({ checkedType, setCheckedType, checkedColor, setCheckedColor }) => {


  const handleTypeChange = event => {
    setCheckedType({
      ...checkedType,
      [event.target.value]: event.target.checked
    })
  }

  const handleColorChange = event => {
    setCheckedColor({
      ...checkedColor,
      [event.target.value]: event.target.checked
    })
  }


    return (
        <div className="stone__nav">
            <h2 className="stone__nav-head">Type</h2>
            <div className="stone__nav-list">
              {checkboxesType.map(item => (
                <label className="stone__nav-var" key={item.key}>
                  {item.value}
                  <StoneFilterListItem
                    id={item.id}
                    value={item.value}
                    checked={checkedType[item.value]}
                    onChange={handleTypeChange}
                  />
                  <span className="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
              ))}
            </div>
            <h2 className="stone__nav-head">Couleur</h2>
            <div className="stone__nav-list">
              {checkboxesColor.map(item => (
                <label className="stone__nav-var" key={item.key}>
                  {item.value}
                  <StoneFilterListItem
                    id={item.id}
                    value={item.value}
                    checked={checkedColor[item.value]}
                    onChange={handleColorChange}
                  />
                  <span className="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
              ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default StoneFilter
```

Here is my component for each checkbox list item:

```
import React from 'react'


const StoneFilterListItem = ({ type = "checkbox", id, value, checked = false, onChange }) => {
    console.log('StoneFilterListItem: ', id, value, checked)
  
    return (
      <input type={type} id={id} value={value} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
    )
  }

  export default StoneFilterListItem
```

Here is the checkboxesType.js used for filtering type, chcekboxesColor,js is similar so don't believe I need to post that too.

```
const checkboxesType = [
    {
      id: "Marbre",
      key: "checkbox1",
      label: "marbre",
      value: "Marbre"
    },
    {
      id: "Granit",
      key: "checkbox2",
      label: "granit",
      value: "Granit"
    },
    {
      id: "Onyx",
      key: "checkbox3",
      label: "onyx",
      value: "Onyx"
    },
    {
      id: "Travertin",
      key: "checkbox4",
      label: "travertin",
      value: "Travertin"
    },
    {
      id: "Quartz",
      key: "checkbox5",
      label: "quartz",
      value: "Quartz"
    },
    {
      id: "Terrazzo",
      key: "checkbox6",
      label: "terrazzo",
      value: "Terrazzo"      
    }   
  ]

  export default checkboxesType
```

Adding App.js just incase too:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Header from '../Header/Header'
import NavBar from '../NavBar/NavBar'
import About from '../About/About'
import StoneDisplay from '../StoneDisplay/StoneDisplay'
import Contact from '../Contact/Contact'
/* import stoneService from '../../services/stones' */
import axios from 'axios'

import './App.css'

const App = () => {
  const [stones, setStones] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect');
    axios
    .get('http://localhost:3001/stones')
    .then(response => {
      console.log('promise fulfilled')
      setStones(response.data)
      })
  }, [])
  console.log('render', stones.length, 'stones')

  return (
    <div className="appContainer">
      <Header />
      <NavBar />
      <About />
      <StoneDisplay stones={stones} />
      <Contact />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here is stones array. Currently using json server for development:

```
{
    "stones": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Bianco Sivec",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/BiancoSivec1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Imperial White",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/ImperialWhite1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Fantasy White",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/FantasyWhite1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Infinito",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/Infinito1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Fantasy Gold",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Beige",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/FatasyGold1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Labareda",
            "type": "Quartz",
            "color": "Multi",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/Labareda1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Honey Blue",
            "type": "Granit",
            "color": "Bleu",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/HoneyBlue1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Black Taurus",
            "type": "Granit",
            "color": "Noir",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/BlackTaurus1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Lavender",
            "type": "Onyx",
            "color": "Bleu",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/Lavender1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Mercury Black",
            "type": "Travertin",
            "color": "Noir",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/MercuryBlack1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Mount Ranier",
            "type": "Quartz",
            "color": "Beige",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/MountRanier1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Red Multicolor",
            "type": "Travertin",
            "color": "Rouge",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/RedMulticolor1.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help or guidance towards what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a code sandbox with the relevant components:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-keldysh-627yx?file=/src/StoneDisplay.js

I have followed the answer presented below and created an instance of state for stonesToShow(still here, just commented out). I keep hitting road blocks so went back to what I had before to try and sort out filter and then will refactor into the suggested implementation.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of stones array?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your detailed implementation, I think you're missing the obvious here: Your `stonesToShow` array will never react to changes made after the initial render. That's because you defined it as a "normal" variable in the component `const stonesToShow = ...` and not as a "React" state `const [stonesToShow, setStonesToShow] = useState(...)`

Here is a very basic example that modifies values in an array, once with `useState` and once with a "normal" variable in the component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-hooks-nsnvt?file=/src/App.tsx

When you click on the "Modify array" button, you can see that React does not rerender based on changes to the "normal variable".
You need `useState`/`useEffect` for that.

So for your example:

```
const StoneDisplay = ({ stones }) => {
  const [stoneType, setStoneType] = useState({})
  const [stoneColor, setStoneColor] = useState({})
  const [stonesToShow, setStonesToShow] = useState(stones) // initialized from props

  useEffect(() => {
    setStonesToShow(currentStones => {
       return currentStones.filter(item => item.type === stoneType.checked && stoneColor.checked)
    })
  }, [stoneType.checked, stoneColor.checked]) // re-filter the array when one of these changes
  ...
```

Using the `useEffect` to set the state will actually trigger a rerender.

Comment: Thank you for this info, however, when I try to implement this instance of state, stonesToShow is not getting initialized from props. i.e. when logging stones in the component, I receive the array of stones. However when I log stonesToShow (as illustrated) I get an empty array.. If I understand correctly useState(stones) is what sets the initial state.

Comment: I assume that `stonesToShow` is initialized correctly (based on your example above), but the filter does not use the right criteria, thus filterting everything in the array. Could you remove the filter (or just change the assignment (`item.type === stoneType.checked && stoneColor.checked` to `true`)), to check whether the fetched data is passed through? If this is the case, you have a problem with the filter check itself, not the React code.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I changed the filter line to this: return currentStones.filter(item => item.type === true) with this change I am still logging an empty array for stonesToShow. I find it confusing as the stones props are being passed to the component as confirmed when logging stones.

Comment: No, I meant disabling the check completely: `return currentStones.filter(item => true)` - this won't filter any item, so you can check whether `StoneDisplay` is showing the data, which confirms that you passed the data correctly from the parent component. If that's the case, your filter check needs some work, not the React code around it.

Comment: Ok, when changed to: return currentStones.filter(item => true) I still am not getting stonesToShow to receive data. It appears I need to adjust how I'm passing the data. Do you have any suggestions as to any avenues to check? I am confused how it could be wrong as the property logs the appropriate data.

Comment: @BennetDams Ultimately, I have not changed anything, but now seems to be working. I did try to follow your suggestion of changing the way I was passing props. At one point I wrapped stones in brackets: const [stonesToShow, setStonesToShow] = useState([stones]) and with this I was able to get stonesToShow to log for an instant (but would get lost on refresh). However, believing this is not correct anyway, upon switching back to the original useState(stones) all of my items rendered using the (item => true) filter statement. I believe this now illustrates an error in my filtering.

Comment: Just to add info, a browser refresh continues to break the app. It will render and log when/after I save from VS code, but no longer render or log if I refresh browser??

Comment: If you can, try to create a CodeSandbox with all your code and some static data you expect from the backend. This would massively help to help.

Comment: @BennetDams CodeSandbox created with link in original question